# Demystifying CSRF?

Tags: security, cookies, jwt, csrf, openid-connect

I've read through a lot of [long explanations of CSRF](http://www.gnucitizen.org/blog/csrf-demystified/) and IIUC the core thing that enables the attack is cookie based identification of server sessions.

So in other words if the browser (And note I'm specifically narrowing the scope to web browsers here) does not use a cookie based session key to identify the session on the server, then a CSRF attack cannot happen.  Did I understand this correctly?

So for example suppose someone creates a link like:

```
 href="http://notsosecurebank.com/transfer.do?acct=AttackerA&amount;=$100">Read more!
```

You are tricked into clicking on this link while logged into `http://notsosecurebank.com`, however `http://notsosecurebank.com` does not use cookies to track your login session, and therefore the link does not do any harm since the request cannot be authenticated and just gets thrown in the garbage?

#### Assumptions

- The OpenID Connect Server / OAuth Authorization server has been implemented correctly and will not send authentication redirects to any URL that you ask it to.
- The attacker does not know the client id and client secret

#### Footnotes

The scenario I'm targeting in this question is the CSRF scenario most commonly talked about.  There are other scenarios that fit the `CSRF` tag.  These scenarios are highly unlikely, yet good to be aware of, and prepared for.  [One of them](https://spring.io/blog/2011/11/30/cross-site-request-forgery-and-oauth2) has the following components:

- 1) The attacker is able to direct you to a bad client
- 2) The attacker owns that client
- 3) The attacker has the secret for that client registered with the OAuth Authorization Server
- 4) The attacker is able to tell the Authorization Server that authenticates you to redirect back to the bad client after you have been authenticated with the proper server.

So setting this up is a little bit like breaking into Fort Knox, but certainly good to be aware of.  For example OpenID Connect or OAuth Authorization Providers should most likely flag clients that register redirect URLs pointing to redirect URLs that other clients have also registered.

Comment: And if you don't use cookies what do you use?

Comment: JWT and XHR / REST requests.  The Authorization header will contain the JWT token.  It's put on the XHR request by the javascript code that creates the request.

Comment: And how you pass JWT? Everytime you will create a token at client side or reuse it?

Comment: You initially obtain the JWT from the OpenID Connect provider / OAuth authorization server and store it in local or session storage.  When you create api requests, the token is read from local storage and included in the Authorization header.

Comment: @Ole Then you can't use HttpOnly and open yourself up to a bigger class of XSS attacks. Building your application correctly (by requiring the proper method to be used for unsafe actions) is better all around.

Comment: IIUC as long as you encode / escape all input fields properly all XSS attacks are avoided?  Also httponly is used to secure a cookie?  I'm saying don't use a cookie for the user session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common / usually discussed [CSRF Cross Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) scenario can only happen when the browser stores credentials (as a cookie or as basic authentication credentials).

OAuth2 implementations (client and authorization server) must be careful about CSRF attacks. CSRF attacks can happens on the client's redirection URI and on the authorization server. According to the [specification (RFC 6749)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12):

> A CSRF attack against the client's redirection URI allows an attacker
> to inject its own authorization code or access token, which can
> **result in the client using an access token associated with the
> attacker's protected resources rather than the victim's** (e.g., save
> the victim's bank account information to a protected resource
> controlled by the attacker).

> The **client MUST implement CSRF protection** for its redirection URI.
> This is typically accomplished by requiring any request sent to the
> redirection URI endpoint to include a value that binds the request to
> the user-agent's authenticated state (e.g., a hash of the session
> cookie used to authenticate the user-agent).  The client SHOULD
> utilize the "state" request parameter to deliver this value to the
> authorization server when making an authorization request.
>
> [...]

> A CSRF attack against the authorization server's authorization
> endpoint can **result in an attacker obtaining end-user authorization
> for a malicious client** without involving or alerting the end-user.

> The **authorization server MUST implement CSRF protection** for its
> authorization endpoint and ensure that a malicious client cannot
> obtain authorization without the awareness and explicit consent of
> the resource owner

Comment: Right but how does the website allow the request to happen?  My understanding is that a cookie identifying the session has to be passed along with the malicious request.  If that cookie is not present, then the session cannot be identified, and no harm can be done?  So it seems like there a two components two a CSRF attack.  A cookie that identifies the browser session with the domain that the attack is targeting and a means of performing the attack (Like an image href, anchor, etc.).

Comment: Yes, the cookie is sent with the crafted request that the user is tricked to send.

Comment: And without that cookie the attack cannot happen?  So as long as the server that not send a Set-Cookie: session = ... header on authentication we can never have a CSRF attack?

Comment: In some applications, the session id is in the url. In this case a malicious url in the website can be considered as a CSRF without cookie.

Comment: Doesn't putting the session id in the URL require the client to perform the logic that puts it there?  In other words the attacker won't know the session id in advance, so they can't put it in a link that performs the attack?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was thinking about the case where the url is injected into the web application such that the complete url with the session id is computed by the application.

Comment: OK - Cool - Thanks for discussing - it's very helpful - Just want to make sure I'm not overlooking something.

Comment: I also updated the answer a little bit to reflect the discussion - hope that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Theory is, CSRF is not related to the authentication method. If an adversary can have a victim user perform actions in another application that the victim didn't want, then that application is vulnerable to CSRF.

This can manifest in several ways, the most common being that a victim user visits a malicious website which in turn makes requests from the victim's browser to another application, thus performing actions the user didn't want. This way it is possible if credentials are sent by the victim browser automatically. By far the most common scenario is a session cookie, but there can be others as well, for example HTTP Basic auth (the browser remembers that as well), or Windows authentication in a domain (Kerberos/SPNEGO), or client certificates, or even some kind of an SSO under certain circumstances.

Also sometimes application authentication is cookie-based, and all non-GET (POST, PUT, etc.) requests are protected against CSRF, but GETs are not for obvious reasons. In languages like PHP, it is easy to make calls intended to be POST requests also work as GETs (think of using `$_REQUEST` in PHP). In that case, any other website can include something like `<img src='http://victim.com/performstuff&param=123>` to have actions performed silently.

There are also less obvious CSRF attacks in complex systems or flows, like for example the [CSRF attacks against oauth](https://spring.io/blog/2011/11/30/cross-site-request-forgery-and-oauth2).

So if a web application uses say tokens (sent as request headers, instead of session cookies) for authentication, meaning a client will have to add the token to each request, that is *probably* not vulnerable to CSRF, but as always, the devil is in the details.

Comment: Thanks - some good bits of info there!  The basic auth comment is also very helpful / good to be aware of.  My end goal is to make sure I don't have any security holes in my openid connect implementation which will be using JWT tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the OAuth attack link as well - Dave is the best!